# regular expressions replace in iOS

Tags: ios, regex, nsregularexpression

I am going to need to replace a dirty string for a clean string:

```
-(void)setTheFilter:(NSString*)filter
{
    [filter retain];
    [_theFilter release];

    <PSEUDO CODE>
    tmp = preg_replace(@"/[0-9]/",@"",filter);
    <~PSEUDO CODE>

    _theFilter = tmp;
}
```

This should eliminate all numbers in the `filter` so that:

@"Import6652"
would yield @"Import"

How can I do it in iOS ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 22):

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:
                              @"([0-9]+)" options:0 error:nil];

[regex replaceMatchesInString:str options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [str length]) withTemplate:@""];
```

**Swift**

```
do {
    let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "([0-9]+)", options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.CaseInsensitive)
    regex.replaceMatchesInString(str, options: NSMatchingOptions.ReportProgress, range: NSRange(0,str.characters.count), withTemplate: "")
} catch {}
```

Answer (score 1):

See the docs for [NSRegularExpression](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

In particular the section titled **Replacing Strings Using Regular Expressions**

Answer (score 1):

String replacing code using regex

**Swift3**

```
extension String {
    func replacing(pattern: String, withTemplate: String) throws -> String {
        let regex = try RegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: .caseInsensitive)
        return regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: self, options: [], range: NSRange(0..<self.utf16.count), withTemplate: withTemplate)
    }
}
```

use

```
var string: String = "Import6652"
do {
    let result = try string.replacing(pattern: "[\\d]+", withTemplate: "")
} catch {
    // error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Though not via a regular expression but you can use `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet`

> **stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet**:
>   Returns a new string made by ***removing from both ends*** of the receiver characters contained in a given
>   character set.

in combination with

> **decimalDigitCharacterSet**
>   Returns a character set containing the characters in the category of Decimal Numbers.

like this:

```
[filter stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet]];
```

**Caveat**: it will only remove the characters at both ends.

Comment: Just one thing to beware, this will only work if the numbers are on the edges (i.e. XXX123 or 123XXX will work, but not XX123XX).  For the information given this answer works perfectly, but I thought I'd chime in anyway in case OP has other sets.

Comment: you are right - added information to my answer to clarifie it!

Answer (score 0):

in iOS 4.0+, you can use `NSRegularExpression`:

Use `matchesInString:options:range:` to get an array of all the matching results.

and then delete them from original string

Comment: You could, but why bother when there are better functions around like the one in MSK's answer?